# Is this queue program right without using isfull() and isempty() method in cprogram?

Tags: c, data-structures, queue

I am beginner in data structures.I tried in **simple way**.I tried sample queue program using c.I coded entire program in my own way.I got the output.but I couldn't used **isfull()** and **isempty()** method in this program.I checked directly **using my own condition**.whether queue is empty or full.can anyone tell me Is this program right or not?I enclosed the output whatever I got.[image]Thanks in advance....

```html
#include<stdio.h>
#define MAX 10
int front=0;
int rear=0;
int a[MAX];
void enqueue(int x);
void dequeue();
void peek();
void display();
main()
{
 enqueue(10);
 enqueue(21);
 enqueue(31);
 dequeue();
    enqueue(19);
    enqueue(07);
    dequeue();
    peek();
 enqueue(93);
 enqueue(73);
 dequeue();
    enqueue(64);
    enqueue(188);
 enqueue(75);

 display();
}
void enqueue(int x)
{
 if(rear==MAX)
 {
    printf("queue is full so, data cannot be inserted\n"); 
 }
 else
 {
    a[rear]=x;
    rear++;
 }
}
void dequeue()
{
    if(front==MAX)
 {
  printf("queue is empty so, data cannot be deleted\n");
 }
 else
 {
  front++;
 } 
}
void peek()
{
 printf("FRONT ELEMENT:%d\n",a[front]);
}
void display()
{
 int i;
 for(i=front;i<=MAX-1;i++)
 {
  printf("%d\n",a[i]);
 }
}
```

Comment: I don't understand what you are asking. You don't need to use `isfull` or `isempty` if you are not checking these cases, besides you didn't implement these functions. Do not use global variables for this. Also your `display` should only display the elements that the current stack holds.

Comment: I am asking this code is right or not?,can I implement this way?

Comment: yes and no. Surly you can implement this way, but it will be a rather ugly implementation. The idea is not bad, but it needs improvements. For example, do not use a global variables, check the bounds before doing operations like push/pop (enqueue/dequeue), encapsulate the structure with a `struct`.

Comment: Thankyou for your concern...

Comment: Your code is not good enough. There are elements that are in need for improvement. See this example for the full implementation: https://gist.github.com/ArnonEilat/4471278